# Getting undefined value for input control

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following `html` and `javascript` code(codepen - https://codepen.io/manuchadha/pen/OJVXdzb), I wan to print the value of the `input` control but I am getting the value as `undefined` - `filename is  undefined`. Why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>some title</title>
    <script src="jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="add-more-answer-div">
      <div id="answer-filename-div">
        <label id="filename-label" for="answer-filename">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="answer-filename" />
        <button
          type="button"
          id="more-answer-button"
          onclick="createNewAnswerSection()"
        >
          Add More Sections
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
function createNewAnswerSection() {
  console.log("will create new answer section");
  var answerNameControl = $("#answer-filename");

  console.log("answer name control is ", answerNameControl);
  if (answerNameControl.value === "") {
    alert("give a filename to the answer");
  } else {
    console.log("filename is ", answerNameControl.value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Using pure Javascript, with value you can get the actual value like this https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/XWbKOEy .. No need of jquery..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `val()` at all *!*

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="add-more-answer-div">
  <div id="answer-filename-div">
    <label id="filename-label" for="answer-filename">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="answer-filename">
    <button type="button" id="more-answer-button" onclick="createNewAnswerSection()">Add More Sections</button>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  function createNewAnswerSection() {
    console.log("will create new answer section");
    var answerNameControl = $("#answer-filename").val();

    console.log("answer name control is ", answerNameControl);
    if (answerNameControl === '') {
      alert("give a filename to the answer");
    } else {
      console.log("filename is ", answerNameControl);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: ah! the name of the method is `val()`. I can't use `value` Thanks

Comment: @ManirajMurugan Already posted this comment under question, no need to post it twice *!* After all, OP used `jQ` , surly this is not only one that want to do with `jQ`

Comment: @Pedram, Thanks for pointing out the repetition of comments.. Have removed the one here.. I agree that OP used ```Jquery``` but he combine both ```JS``` and ```Jquery``` to achieve this so I said without ```Jquery```, it is possible in pure ```JS``` itself.. Even this is not the only thing he want to do with ```jquery```, It solves his current question without ```jquery```..

Answer (score 1):

Please use answerNameControl.val() instead of answerNameControl.value

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the syntax of jQuery , You are using `answerNameControl.value` which is not the valid synatx instead you can use `$(answerNameControl).val()` to get the value
Your updated code is as below

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>some title</title>
<script src="jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

                  <div  id="add-more-answer-div">
                    <div id="answer-filename-div">
                        <label id="filename-label" for="answer-filename">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="answer-filename">
                        <button type="button" id="more-answer-button" onclick="createNewAnswerSection()">Add More Sections</button>
                    </div>
                  </div> 


</body>


</html>
<script>
function createNewAnswerSection(){
    console.log("will create new answer section");
    var answerNameControl = $("#answer-filename");

            console.log("answer name control is ",answerNameControl);
            if($(answerNameControl).val() === ''){
                alert("give a filename to the answer"); 
            } else {
                    console.log("filename is ",$(answerNameControl).val());
            } 
    }
```